# How do I handle nan values while using pandas join function?

Tags: join, nan

My dataframe initially looks like this :

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| a | b | d |
| a | b | nan |
| e | f | nan |

Dataframe after replacing nan values with empty string:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| a | b | d |
| a | b | '' |
| e | f | '' |

I want the dataframe to look like:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c,d |
| e | f |  |

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

airflow_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/syc/astro-airflow-localdev/dags/export_dataframe.csv")
cols = ['trgt_schema','trgt_tbl','src_tbl']
subset_airflow = pd.DataFrame(airflow_df, columns=cols)
trgt_df_explode = subset_airflow.assign(src_tbl=t_df.src_tbl.str.split(',')).explode('src_tbl')
trgt_df_explode['src_tbl']=trgt_df_explode['src_tbl'].str.lower()
trgt_df_explode['src_tbl']=trgt_df_explode['src_tbl'].str.strip()
trgt_df_explode = trgt_df_explode.drop_duplicates()
trgt_df_explode_nan= trgt_df_explode.replace(np.nan, None , regex=True)
trgt_df_explode_nan['src_tbl'] = trgt_df_explode_nan.groupby(['trgt_schema','trgt_tbl'])['src_tbl'].transform(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)))
trgt_df_explode = trgt_df_explode.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropna() function. More details: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?

Comment: Dropna removes my fourth column, I don't want that to be removed.

Comment: Then fillna will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).